# generated document template defaulting value to number field instead of text

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

Ive managed to get a document generated when a phone is set up for my system. ive got a word document set up providing the information for the phone with the company policies on. for some reason the mobile phone number quick links field seems to looking at the field as a number and taking off the "0" from the phone number and i cant quite work out how to change it to look at the field as line of text instead?

Its linked to a site column thats listed as single line of text but somewhere along the process when the document is generated into the document library its changing the field to number. i dont think its word thats the issue because in the document library the mobile phone number column seems to be cutting off the "o" aswell

This might be something really simple that im missing but any advise would be most appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a simple enough work around was to add a zero to the beginning of the string in the workflow email seeing as its a phone number it will always begin with 0